# react-query hook is mounted before setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-query

I want to call `console.log(email)` in `onError` part of react-query `useMutation` Hook. However, the `''` value is output to console.

Looking at the code, if an `isError` error is occurring, we put text into `setEmail`, and after `onError` occurs, we print `console.log(email)`.

If I take a `console.log(email)`, it is being called with an empty value, but I want to print `"hi isError"`.

The logic is that when button is clicked, `handleSocialLogin` mutate function is called, `isError` is mounted in `useEffect`, then `setEmail("hi isError")` is saved in `isError`, then `console.log(email)` is being called in `onError` part.

```js
export const googleLogin = (data: any) => {
  return axios.post("/login/google", data).then(({ data }) => data as any);
};

const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
const { mutate, isLoading, isError } = useMutation(googleLogin, {
  onError(error: AxiosError) {
    console.log(email);
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError) {
    setEmail("hi isError");
  }
}, [isError]);

function handleSocialLogin(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> & any) {
  mutate({
    clientIp: "hi",
  });
}

return <button onClick={handleSocialLogin}>button</button>;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply put `setEmail("hi isError")` in the `onError`?

Comment: @Hao-JungHsieh If I set `setEmail('hi error')` as onError and run `console.log(email)` in onError , '' is called with empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onError would execute at almost the same time as the `isError` change in the mutation hook. The `useEffect` is detecting the `isError` change and then executes, which means it will happen after the `onError`.

You can try this if you want to console the result.

```
export const googleLogin = (data: any) => {
  return axios.post("/login/google", data).then(({ data }) => data as any);
};

const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
const { mutate, isLoading, isError } = useMutation(googleLogin, {
  onError(error: AxiosError) {
    setEmail("hi isError");
  },
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (isError) {
    console.log(email);
  }
}, [isError, email]);

function handleSocialLogin(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> & any) {
  mutate({
    clientIp: "hi",
  });
}

return <button onClick={handleSocialLogin}>button</button>;
```